# How to display incoming data notification to android (android studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

how do I make a notification when data goes into database and displayed in android notification?
Now I make an android app to report the disaster, and when someone reports then the report data will be in my android notification.
I use the firebase database and android studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase Cloud Functions for this.

You can get Firebase to react to a trigger (such as writing to the realtime database at a specific place), which you can then use to send notifications.

Please write code for more details and show your work.